# MySQL - How to insert the current date as Unix time stamp?

Tags: mysql, database, unix-timestamp

I have a table called 'products' with some columns. One of them is called 'date' and should contain the date on which the product was added as Unix time stamp. Normally I would use the NOW() function but since the value needs to be an integer and I can't cast the NOW() function as integer, I need to find another way. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a function with the surprising name [`unix_timestamp`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
INSERT INTO `products`
(`name`, `date`)
VALUES ('some name', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify the column to be of type `TIMESTAMP` and set it's default value (if you want to set the column to the date it was added on) to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
ALTER TABLE `products` MODIFY `date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

TIMESTAMP is not a string but an integer timestamp, it is just displayed as a string and you can use operators on it.

With `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` you don't need to insert the date, mysql will do it for you.